# PIR sensor compenent in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Please, I want to add a PIR (motion) sensor to my circuitikz drawing.I can't find any thing in the the official manual or the Internet, any idea?

Comment: Hi, welcome. What does such a symbol look like?

Comment: some thing similar to this https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mivpj-HJh_A/V923L_i5aCI/AAAAAAAAAKw/UEPFhIusE2USqR4Y3A6C8ejdFWO3L2PhwCLcB/s1600/infrared%2Bschematic%2Bsymbol.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code defines a new circuitikz shape with some usefull anchors. The parameters `pir/height`, `pir/pitch`, `pir/width` and `pir/radius` allows to change the size of the new shape.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\ctikzset{
    pir/height/.initial=1.4cm,
    pir/pitch/.initial=0.6cm,
    pir/width/.initial=0.5cm,
    pir/radius/.initial=0.5cm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{pir}{
\anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
\savedanchor\topleft{%
    \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/pitch}
    \pgf@x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/width}
    \pgf@x=-1.5\pgf@x
}
\anchor{power}{\topleft}
\anchor{out}{\topleft\pgf@y=0pt}
\anchor{ground}{\topleft\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
\savedanchor\top{%
    \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/height}
    \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
    \pgf@x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/width}
    \pgf@x=-.5\pgf@x
}
\anchor{north}{\top}
\anchor{south}{\top\pgf@y=-\pgf@y}
\anchor{east}{\pgf@y=0pt\pgf@x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/radius}}

\savedanchor\topleftbox{%
    \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/height}
    \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y
    \pgf@x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/width}
    \pgf@x=-\pgf@x
}

\foregroundpath{
    \pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color}}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth} 

    \topleftbox
    \pgf@circ@res@up=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/height}
    \pgf@circ@res@up=0.5\pgf@circ@res@up
    \pgf@circ@res@down=-\pgf@circ@res@up
    \pgf@circ@res@left=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/width}
    \pgf@circ@res@left=-\pgf@circ@res@left
    \pgf@circ@res@right=0cm
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{
        \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}
    }{
        \pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}
    }
    \pgf@circ@res@right=\pgf@circ@res@left
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/radius}}}
    \pgfpatharc{90}{-90}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/pir/radius}}
    \pgfusepath{draw} 
    \topleft
    \pgf@circ@res@up=\pgf@y
    \pgf@circ@res@left=\pgf@x
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{ \pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{ \pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{-\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{-\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{.5\pgflinewidth} 
    \pgfusepath{draw} 
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[pir] (pir) {}
            (pir.power) node[anchor=east] {power}
            (pir.ground) node[anchor=east] {ground}
            (pir.out) node[anchor=east] {output}
            (pir.north) node[anchor=south] {north}
            (pir.south) node[anchor=north] {south}
            (pir.east) node[anchor=west] {east};
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]